# Fixing footer while using jquery .hide()

Tags: jquery, html, css

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7y6n5/2/

When a person clicks the links (the "broken" images at the bottom), the content div should refresh and display the new content. But you see what's happening with the footer: It moves up and down, along with the animation. I needs it to be fixed in place. How would I achieve that?

`Position: fixed;` or `absolute;` didn't seem to work on the footer class.

Comment: It would be easier for us to fix this if you cut out all the irrelevant styles from the fiffle.

Comment: Ok, done. (More characters here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wrap your `.content` div in a `container` div, and wrap both your `.navbar` and `.footer` divs in a `footercontainer` div.

**CSS**:

Added `position: relative;` to `.main` as well as changing the footer CSS to:

```
.footer {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #505050;
}
```

and finally adding CSS for the two new container divs:

```
#container {
    padding-bottom: 30px;  /* padding for the footer */
}

#footercontainer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:30px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
```

[​Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/8hgkN/2/).

Comment: Yeah, on the way home I was thinking about wrapping it in another div. Thanks for the suggestion, this seems to work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This works in the example

```
.footer {
    background: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #505050;
    position :fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```